# Atalho para criar construtor com parâmetros

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, construtor, resharper

Existe algum atalho no Visual Studio, que cria um construtor, com todos os atributos criados na classe?

```
class Alimento
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Titulo { get; set; }
    public string SubTitulo { get; set; }        
    public string Conteudo  { get; set; }        
    public string Filtro { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataCriacao { get; set; }
    public string NomeImagem { get; set; }
    public string DicasCuriosidades { get; set; }      
    public string Umidade  { get; set; }
    public string Energia_kcal { get; set; }
    public string Proteina_g { get; set; }
    public string Lipideos_g { get; set; }
    public string Saturados_g { get; set; }
    public string Mono_insaturados_g  { get; set; }
    public string Poli_insaturados_g  { get; set; }
    public string Colesterol_mg { get; set; }
    public string Carbo_idrato_g { get; set; }
    public string fibra_alimentar_g  { get; set; }
    public string Calcio_mg { get; set; }
    public string Magnesio_mg { get; set; }
    public string Manganes_mg { get; set; }
    public string Fosforo_mg { get; set; }
    public string Ferro_mg { get; set; }
    public string Sodio_mg { get; set; }
    public string Potassio_mg { get; set; }
    public string Zinco_mg  { get; set; }
    public string Retinol_mcg  { get; set; }
    public string Re_mcg  { get; set; }
    public string Rae_mcg { get; set; }
    public string Tiamina_mg  { get; set; }                                                                                                                                                                     
    public string Riboflavina_mg  { get; set; }
    public string Piridoxina_mg  { get; set; }
    public string Niacina_mg  { get; set; }
    public string Vitamina_c  { get; set; }

    public Alimento(int id, string titulo, ............)
    {
        ID = id;
        Titulo = titulo;            
        ............
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Até onde eu sei, nativamente não existe, ou pelo menos não existia. Não posso afirmar no Visual Studio 2015 que tem novos auxiliadores de código. Pode ser que exista algum plugin que faça isto ([este por exemplo](http://cometaddin.codeplex.com/), não sei se é bom e provavelmente não existe mais quando ler isto).

Acho que o [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_generation.html#Generate_Type_Constructor) faz o que você deseja com um <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd>.

Eu sei que o Visual Studio consegue gerar o construtor à partir do seu uso, mas não é o que você deseja.

É possível que alguém faça algo para isto já que o novo compilador .NET Compiler Platform (antigo Roslyn) facilita muito analisar código. Existe até um projeto brasileiro onde estão fazendo refatorações. Se não achar nada, e não souber como fazer um, pede para o pessoal que participa do [Code-Cracker](https://github.com/code-cracker/code-cracker) (projeto meio abandonado) fazer um gerador de código para você.

De qualquer forma já aviso que não é uma das tais boas práticas fazer um construtor com tantos parâmetros. Talvez o que você deveria usar é um gerador de código que crie um [inicializador do objeto](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) na sua declaração. O resultado será essencialmente o mesmo se não houver concorrência. Mesmo que tenha, dificilmente haverá problemas neste caso. Ele criaria algo assim:

```
var alimento = new Alimento(identificador, titulo) {
    SubTitulo = subtitulo,
    Conteudo = conteudo,
    ...
    ...
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/Instanciation.cs).

Tem outras implicações na forma como você está fazendo, talvez você esteja violando o encapsulamento criando propriedades para todos os membros, mas não vou entrar nisto porque não faz parte do escopo da pergunta.

[Mais informações sobre construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101).

Em C# 9 pode usar os [geradores de código](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-c-source-generators/) para criar isso para você. Antes dava mas eram mais complicado.

Comment: Sou novo na ária de desenvolvimento, como passado os parâmetros para o construtor? seguindo o critério de boas praticas?

Comment: Não passa a não ser que ele realmente seja necessário no construtor. Não dá para responder aqui o motivo de existir um construtor mas você não precisa necessariamente inicializar todos os membros pelo construtor. Tem alguns casos onde isso realmente é necessário. Resumidamente você só faz isto quando precisa que a inicialização seja feita antes do objeto estar disponível. Isso não costuma ser uma necessidade real na maioria dos casos. O melhor é inicializar os membros pelas suas propriedades conforme mostrei acima. Isto até está mais fácil no C# 6. De qq forma dei uma melhorada na resposta.

Comment: "O resultado será essencialmente o mesmo se não houver concorrência." - Mesmo que haja concurrencia, o resultado será o mesmo. Quando se usa um *object initializer*, o objecto só é *publicado* depois de os setters serem executados. (Por *publicação* de um objecto, entenda-se a atribuição do objecto à variável `alimento`)

Comment: @dcastro é verdade, pra concorrência realmente não faz diferença desde que o *object initializer* foi criado, embora tecnicamente a criação é feita de forma diferente do que seria com o construtor. Neste caso só haveria problemas se precisasse realmente fazer alguma operação na construção. O exemplo dele não parece fazer muito sentido ter um construtor, salvo ele ter algum requerimento não descrito. Em tese nem mesmo os 2 parâmetros, que eu criei no exemplo só para mostrar que é possível mesclar, seriam necessários.

Comment: Concordo, não faz sentido criar um constructor. Aliás, a própria classe com tantas propriedades é logo um *code smell*...

Comment: Entendi pessoal.
Porem o construtor esta sendo usado sim, este objeto é instanciado na camada repositório, que faz conexão com o banco de dados, e inicializa com todos os parâmetros descritos aqui....

Comment: @EduardoF.Santos precisa ver exatamente como isto está sendo feito, não vou continuar nisso porque já é outro assunto que não cabe aqui na pergunta, mas você já teve boas informações aqui para pelo menos pensar melhor no *design* desta classe.

Answer (score 1):

Digita (**ctor + TAB + TAB**) é o atalho para o construtor padrão.

Não esqueça de utilizar a segurança do private usando os getters and setters.

atalho para encapsulamento (get/set) é: (**Control + .**)

Selecionando o get/set gerando e pressionando também o (**Control + .**) ele gera o construtor com o parâmetro selecionado.