# Para que serve um construtor?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, classes, terminologia, construtor

Em geral classes possuem métodos construtores.

Qual a utilidade do método construtor de uma classe? Por que devemos criá-lo? Dá para trabalhar sem ele?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Nem sempre um [construtor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_(object-oriented_programming)) é necessário. Há linguagens que se viram bem sem um onde sequer é possível criar um construtor.

Construtores devem dar **atomicidade** na criação do objeto. Ou seja, ou cria o objeto em um estado válido ou não cria.

## Quando usar

#### Validação

Se você precisa validar os dados e se alguma validação falhar o objeto não deve ser criado, então um construtor ajuda bastante. Isto é especialmente verdade se para validar um membro um outro já deve estar em estado válido. Fica complicado controlar isto se os membros podem ser inicializados independentemente.

#### Processamento

O mesmo vale se algum processamento seja necessário com os parâmetros iniciais antes de criar o objeto. Entre esses processamentos podemos incluir a aquisição de recursos externos, como banco de dados, acesso ao sistema de arquivos, redes, etc., mas pode ser apenas cálculos simples.

#### Ordem de execução

O construtor também permite determinar a ordem como cada membro é inicializado, seja automaticamente ou manualmente. Sem um construtor o compilador ou o *runtime* da linguagem determinará a ordem de inicialização dos membros, o que pode ser documentado ou não, até porque pode não ser determinístico. Obviamente não é possível lidar com formas complexas de inicialização de forma automática. Isto pode ser útil não só para determinar o fluxo correto do processamento mas também validar corretamente.

#### Concorrência

A criação atômica é especialmente importante quando temos processamento concorrente. Em hipótese alguma podemos disponibilizar o estado de um objeto que pode ser compartilhado com outros caminhos de processamento sem que o objeto esteja inicializado por completo. Entenda "por completo" como o mínimo para gerar um estado válido, não quer dizer que todos os membros precisam estar inicializados, até porque alguns podem ser opcionais mesmo.

## Quais dados devem ser passados para o construtor?

Só faz sentido passar para um construtor dados que precisam existir obrigatoriamente em um objeto de forma válida ou que precisam ser processados antes de serem inseridos no objeto.

Se nenhum dado é obrigatório para ter um estado válido ou é possível que todos os dados tenham valores padrões (*default*) válidos na sua criação, o construtor não é necessário.

Isso não quer dizer que não possa existir, mas faz pouco sentido criar um construtor que aceite dados que não sejam obrigatórios desde o momento zero de sua criação. Embora possa fazer sentido em algumas linguagens que não possuem formas mais convenientes de inicialização de membros.

Em geral é até melhor inicializar os membros pelas suas propriedades assim você os nomina e documenta melhor o código. Isto é possível também em um construtor se a linguagem possuir argumentos nomeados, como é o caso do C#, por exemplo.

## Construtor padrão

Algumas linguagens possuem um construtor padrão sem parâmetros que é usado para a inicialização padrão, mas em geral ele é criado pelo compilador e o programador não precisa se preocupar. Evidentemente que as linguagens que não possuem o mecanismo de construtor acabam inicializando o novo objeto de alguma forma simplificada ou deixa lixo de memória disponível.

## Inicialização sem construtor

Algumas linguagens provêm outras formas de inicializar objetos de forma análoga ou pelo menos aproximada ao que o construtor permite. Claro que provavelmente com limitações. As formas mais comuns são a inicialização por padrão (por defeito) e a inicialização durante a criação do objeto. A segunda deve possuir uma sintaxe e semântica própria na linguagem ou pelo menos uma infraestrutura que ajude a atomicidade, a ordem de execução, etc. C# e C++11 possuem (no fundo acabam tendo um construtor, afinal só funções podem ter execução).

## Construtores não são obrigatórios.

Um erro comum é achar que toda classe deve possuir construtor. Claro que pode existir alguma linguagem que obrigue a sua criação (além do construtor padrão) por algum motivo, mas desconheço algum caso. Normalmente é possível criar um objeto e inicializar seus membros de outras formas, e exceto pelos casos citados acima, sem nenhum problema ou dificuldade.

Se você não sabe porque está criando um construtor provavelmente está criando-o desnecessariamente. Por outro lado, se você não entender todas as implicações de se criar um objeto de forma parcial, não saberá quando o construtor é necessário. Também se você nem pensou se seu objeto precisa de construtor, precisa estudar melhor o assunto.

Note que criar um objeto sem ter todos os membros inicializados juntos não é um problema por si só, na maioria das linguagens, especialmente aquelas que inicializam os membros com algum valor *default*. Pode ser um pouco mais problemático em linguagens que não inicializam os membros e podem conter "lixo" como seu conteúdo. Depende do contexto da classe o que realmente precisa ser inicializado por um construtor e o que pode ser deixado para ser resolvido ou pelo valor *default* ou após a criação do objeto, seja por um inicializador ou através de propriedades individuais. A criação por padrão ocorrerá em alguma forma de construtor, mesmo que invisível para o programador.

Idealmente o construtor explícito só deve existir se realmente ele é necessário e só deve receber os parâmetros mínimos para gerar um estado válido manipulando a menor quantidade possível de membros. A preferência, **sempre que possível**, é que os membros sejam ou inicializados por padrão (ou defeito) ou individualmente no código que vai consumi-lo.

Também não deixe de criar um construtor quando ele traz vantagem, conveniência ou mesmo legibilidade.

## Funções construtoras

Mesmo quando uma linguagem não possui construtores formalmente ainda é possível criar funções que fazem o mesmo trabalho. Isto é comum até mesmo em linguagens que possuem o mecanismo explicitamente. Muitas vezes esta forma é conhecida como [Factory Method Pattern](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157466/101) mas pode assumir outras formas.

## Termo

O termo é um pouco incorreto, no fundo se ele fosse chamado de **inicializador** seria melhor entendido. Pra mim a construção se dá pela alocação mais a inicialização.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: O cara pergunta, e o cara responde :)

Comment: Eu vi que tem muita gente que não entende bem sobre isso e já tinha lugares para linkar essa resposta canônica. Ainda vou melhorá-la mas estou com pouco tempo.

Comment: Não sei se vale a pena incluir na resposta porque não é uma característica dos construtores em geral, mas em linguagens que suportam *overloading* de métodos, é muito útil ter múltiplos construtores com diferentes assinaturas. Evita ter de criar várias classes derivadas, ou uma estrutura que fabrique instâncias diferentes conforme parâmetros variáveis em tipo e quantidade.

Comment: @bigown o que seria este **lixo de memória**? Existe resposta que fala a respeito?

Comment: @drmcarvalho imagino que não. Isto é pegar qualquer coisa que estiver lá na memória. Alocar memória não é colocar nada nela, fica o que estiver lá. Por isso precisa da inicialização.

Answer (score 26):

Sim, dá para trabalhar sem implementar código no construtor da classe.

> A principal utilidade de se implementar o construtor do objeto é exigir parâmetros sem os quais o objeto não pode viver sem, sem os quais ele não faz sentido.

Se para fazer o seu trabalho um objeto exige alguns dados ou possui algumas dependências, faz sentido exigir que isso lhe seja passado já no construtor, a fim de tornar estas **dependências explícitas** e a fim de garantir que o objeto esteja num estado válido antes de pedir que ele execute algum trabalho ou antes de passá-lo como parâmetro para outro objeto ou serviço.

## Exemplo de onde um construtor cai bem

Considere um objeto repositório de entidades. Este objeto oferece métodos de negócio que entregam e persistem entidades.

Para funcionar, este repositório depende de um objeto que forneça acesso ao banco de dados.

Então esta é uma opção de implementação deste repositório (sem implementar o construtor):

```java
class ClientesRepo {
    
    Dao dao;
    
    void setDataAccessObject(Dao dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }
    List<Cliente> clientesAtivos() {
        return dao.executeQuery("select c from Cliente c where c.ativo = 'S'");
    }
}
```

Utilizando o objeto acima, eu só posso consumir o método *clientesAtivos* depois de setar a propriedade *setDataAccessObject*, então a dependência que o objeto tem de um *Dao* não está explícita, **a abstração foi quebrada**: eu terei que olhar o código dentro da classe para entender o que ela precisa para funcionar.

Implementar o construtor ajuda a tornar a dependência explícita:

```java
class ClientesRepo {

    Dao dao;
    
    ClientesRepo(Dao dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }
    List<Cliente> clientesAtivos() {
        return dao.executeQuery("select c from Cliente c where c.ativo = 'S'");
    }
}
```

Agora, quando o consumidor instanciar um repositório de clientes, ele notará imediatamente as dependências deste repositório, e é obrigado pelo compilador a informar esta dependência.

**O código ficou mais seguro, mais expressivo.**

Comment: Ao definir este contrutor com parâmetros o construtor padrão já é sobrescrito ou ele continua acessível mesmo sem estar definido?

Answer (score 15):

Um construtor serve para instanciar objetos da classe na qual esse construtor foi definido.

A inicialização de objetos por meio de construtores é necessária para evitar erro de referência nula quando usando objetos que foram declarados mas não inicializados.

O código abaixo, escrito em C#, cria uma classe com um construtor e utiliza esse construtor para inicializar um objeto do tipo de dado definido por esta classe:

```cs
// Define uma classe.
public class Classe
{
    // Define uma propriedade nessa classe.
    public int Propriedade { get; set; }

    // Construtor padrão.
    public Classe()
    {
        // código de inicialização da classe aqui, caso o construtor padrão for utilizado na criação do objeto.
    }

    // Define um construtor simples para a classe, recebendo um parâmetro numérico.
    public Classe(int parametro)
    {
        this.Propriedade = parametro;
    }
}

public class Main()
{
    // Cria um objeto utilizando o construtor padrão.
    Classe objeto = new Classe();

    // Cria um objeto utilizando o construtor de parâmetro numérico.
    Classe outroObjeto = new Classe(10);
}
```

É essencialmente um método que retorna um objeto do próprio tipo da classe, e pode receber parâmetros assim como qualquer outro método.

Você pode trabalhar sem construtores. Caso não definir nenhum construtor, geralmente a linguagem de programação irá criar um construtor padrão implicitamente, sem parâmetros, como mostrado no exemplo acima.

Comment: A questão é que se você não tiver esses construtores, este código vai funcionar sem problemas. Terá uma desvantagem quando você precisa inicializar o membro com 10 e este é realmente o problema, que você não citou. A pergunta é sobre sua serventia e não o que é.

Answer (score 5):

O construtor pode ser usado para instanciar um objeto...

```
// Define uma classe.
public class Classe
{
    // Define uma propriedade nessa classe.
    public int Propriedade { get; set; }

    public IColletion<Classe2> Classe2 { get; set; }

    // Construtor padrão.
    public Classe()
    {   
        Instanciando uma lista através do contrutor
        Classe2 = new List<Classe2>();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Como assim, "também"?

Comment: O construtor com paramentos pode ser usado para passar valores e o construtor vazio, pode ser usado para instanciar um objeto dentro da classe @bigown

Comment: Mas não estou entendendo o "também". `O construtor pode ser usado para instanciar um objeto`. Ponto. É só pra isso que ele pode ser usado. De qualquer forma, note que a pergunta é um pouco mais complexa que isso.

Comment: @bigown Entendi o que você quis dizer... mas para ser sincero, não achei muitas explicações sobre essa forma de usar o construtor, nem o melhor momento, talvez por isso eu não tenha me explicado direito na postagem...
De qualquer forma, obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

De uma forma simples, é um método que é executado quando da instanciação do objeto. O interessante dele é que você pode garantir que um novo objeto terá um conjunto de valores preenchidos.

Answer (score -2):

Todo código vai com um construtor vazio embutido nele, porém quando você precisar utilizar dados em ordens diferentes na classe principal você precisará dos construtores.